# Nginx - reverse proxy prevent needing port number in url

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a React app that runs on `https://localhost:3000`.

I have a domain like `https://example.com/some/path`.

When I enter `https://example.com/some/path` into my browser, I'd like it to redirect to `https://localhost:3000`. So the way I've seen this possible is using a reverse proxy and I'm trying to nginx setup to do so.

However I keep facing in an issue that I need include the port number when I go to the full url for example: `https://example.com:3000/some/path`.

How do i prevent this from happening? i.e. I'd like to just enter `https://example.com/some/path`.

My nginx conf file looks like this:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  example.com;

        ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

        location /some/path {
        return 301 $scheme://localhost:3000$request_uri;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }


    server {
        listen 3000 ssl;

        ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

        server_name localhost;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

        location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
    }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

And in my hosts file I have the line:

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
```

Even if I keep it simple and have only one server section with location like:

```
location /some/path {
   proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
}
```

That kind of works - however looking at the console the assets themselves don't load `https://example.com/static/js/bundle.js` when it needs to be `https://example.com:3000/static/js/bundle.js`

Any help would be appreciated.